# How can I send data from a raspberry pi to my laptop?

Tags: sqlite, networking, raspberry-pi

I need a simple way of sending a string from my raspberry pi to my laptop (on the same WiFi network) and then store in a Sqlite database.

Comment: What technology do you want to use? If you know what technology you want you should find examples on the internet. If you want a recommendation for a technology this is probably the wrong place to ask.

Comment: A database server that works over a network, like Postgresql or MariaDB, is a better choice than sqlite for this usage.

Comment: You can simply send and receive strings with `netcat` also known as `nc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most basic way could be through socket programming :

Code on raspberrypi :

```
import socket                

s = socket.socket()          

port = 12345                

s.connect(('<your_ip_address>', port)) 

s.send('Hello this is your rpi') 

s.close()
```

Code on your laptop :

```
import socket                

s = socket.socket()          
print "Socket successfully created"

port = 12345                

s.bind(('<your_ip_address>', port))         
print "socket binded to %s" %(port) 

s.listen(5)      
print "socket is listening"            

while True: 

   c, addr = s.accept()      
   print 'Got connection from', addr 

   c.send('Thank you for connecting') 

   c.close()
```

Another way could be through mqtt where you will have to set up an mqtt server on the pi and a client on the laptop, the raspberrypi would then send messages over a specific topic which the client (laptop) can subscribe to and keep listening to it till a message is received.

You can refer to [python mqtt script on raspberry pi to send and receive messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37006863/python-mqtt-script-on-raspberry-pi-to-send-and-receive-messages) for the same

Comment: Are both IPs the laptops? I'll be doing it over WiFI so IP will likely be 192.168.1.1 or something.

Comment: Yes the ip would be laptop's only and that ip would be your wifi ip so it would be 192.168.x.x sorts only